# creating a TextFormField with rounded corners and no ActivationIndicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement a user input for a code that looks like [image]

Currently, all I have is one container housing a row that contains 4 containers each containing a TextFormField. How do I achieve the above

```
   Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: new Form(
            child: Container(
               color: Colors.blue[100],
               height: 100.0,
               width: 350.0,
               child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment:
                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                         color: Colors.amber,
                         height: 50.0,
                         width: 50.0,
                         child: TextFormField(),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            height: 50.0,
                            width: 50.0,
                            child: TextFormField(),
                             ),
                           Container(
                           color: Colors.amber,
                           height: 50.0,
                           width: 50.0,
                            child: TextFormField(),
                            ),
                            Container(
                           color: Colors.amber,
                           height: 50.0,
                           width: 50.0,
                            child: TextFormField(),
                            ),

                      ),
                                  ],
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i created [this](https://gist.github.com/Rahiche/3eecad575fbb3c87b3f41d14612291b7) little example and i think this will help you to achieve the same think.and to recap :

- you need to change the focus from `TextField` to another using the `FoucusNode`
- you can change the border and the other decoration setting from the decoration property but if you want to change something like the color it's always good to use the `Theme` widget and change the theme from there
- if you want to pervert the user from typing more then one charterer use `LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter`
- you can get the Rounded corners and specific  the border raduis  also from the decoration

  ```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      hintText: "0",
  ),
  ```

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. I also needed a way to save the inputted digits. And how do i stop it from iterating after entering the last digit. By the way, this is a firebase code verification code. So, in the end, I will need to submit it, how do i save what user has entered

Comment: After entering all the digits. The digits should remain in place and then I submit. Also the user may need to delete one number, going from right to left, how can this happen. This is why I was using the TextFormField, the TextField seems to require a lot of manual workarounds

Comment: i can give an answer here but that's another question so the part that make the focus node moves is [this](https://gist.github.com/Rahiche/3eecad575fbb3c87b3f41d14612291b7#file-code-input-example-L106) just remove it and it will not move directly

Comment: i created this [widget](https://github.com/Rahiche/flutter_code_input) and hope it will help